# String contains trailing zeroes when converted from decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, winforms

I've run into an unusual quirk in a program I'm writing, and I was trying to figure out if anyone knew the cause. Note that **fixing** the issue is easy enough. I just can't figure out why it is happening in the first place.

I have a WinForms program written in *VB.NET* that is displaying a subset of data. It contains a few labels that show numeric values (the `.Text` property of the labels are being assigned directly from the Decimal values). These numbers are being returned by a DLL I wrote in *C#*. The DLL calls a webservice which initially returns the values in question. It returns one as a string, the other as a decimal (I don't have any control over the webservice, I just consume it). The DLL assigns these to properties on an object (both of which are decimals) then returns that object back to the WinForm program that called the DLL. Obviously, there's a lot of other data being consumed from the webservice, but no other operations are happening which could modify these properties.

So, the short version is:

- WinForm requests a new `Foo` from the DLL.
- DLL creates object `Foo`.
- DLL calls webservice, which returns `SomeOtherFoo`.

  ```
  //Both Foo.Bar1 and Foo.Bar2 are decimals
  Foo.Bar1 = decimal.Parse(SomeOtherFoo.Bar1); //SomeOtherFoo.Bar1 is a string equal to "2.9000"
  Foo.Bar2 = SomeOtherFoo.Bar2; //SomeOtherFoo.Bar2 is a decimal equal to 2.9D
  ```
- DLL returns Foo to WinForm.

  ```
  WinForm.lblMockLabelName1.Text = Foo.Bar1 //Inspecting Foo.Bar1 indicates my value is 2.9D
  WinForm.lblMockLabelName2.Text = Foo.Bar2 //Inspecting Foo.Bar2 also indicates I'm 2.9D
  ```

So, what's the quirk?

WinForm.lblMockLabelName1.Text displays as **"2.9000"**, whereas WinForm.lblMockLabelname2.Text displays as **"2.9"**.

Now, everything I know about C# and VB indicates that the format of the string which was initially parsed into the decimal should have no bearing on the outcome of a later decimal.ToString() operation called on the same decimal. I would expect that `decimal.Parse(someDecimalString).ToString()` would return the string without any trailing zeroes. Everything I find online seems to corroborate this (there are countless Stack Overflow questions asking exactly the opposite...how to keep the formatting from the initial parsing).

At the moment, I've just removed the trailing zeroes from the initial string that gets parsed, which has hidden the quirk. However, I'd love to know why it happens in the first place.

Comment: I would modify the declaration of `SomeOtherFoo.Bar2` to be set at 2.9000D just to make them truly "equivalent". My thinking is that the `Parse` is retaining the decimal precision even though the right 3 digits are 0.

Comment: Dunno if this will solve your quirk, but I had some double and decimal parsing problems some time ago, and `Decimal.Parse(stringNumber,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` did the job for me

Comment: Are the two decimals really the same? Does Foo.Bar1==Foo.Bar2?

Comment: @JoelEtherton I have no control over SomeOtherFoo. It's returned to me by a webservice I'm consuming. As mentioned, though, I'm not particularly concerned with "fixing" it - I've done that already. The question was if anyone knew why it was occurring, when everything seems to suggest that the decimal should retain no knowledge of how it was initially formatted. You mentioned precision...but don't all decimals inherently have the same precision?

Comment: I just tested your code real quick like this and it yields `2.9000`
var somemString = decimal.Parse("2.9000").ToString(); do you have some max length set on that label or something

Comment: @Locke: I meant replace your comparison with a variable that operates in this manner as a testing apparatus. You control the interface so instead of just supplying the service provided value, use your own temporarily.

Comment: @JoelEtherton Sorry, I misunderstood your comment at first. What I ended up doing is just trimming any trailing zeroes, then converting it to a decimal. I was just under the impression that conversion to a decimal effectively removed any previous formatting.

Comment: @DJKRAZE No max length on the labels, no.

Comment: @Locke: I would think the same thing, but after reading some of the type documentation it made me wonder if it was possible that the decimal type had some method of maintaining that precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the scaling factor also [preserves any trailing zeros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) in a Decimal number. Trailing zeros do not affect the value of a Decimal number in arithmetic or comparison operations. However, trailing zeros might be revealed by the ToString method if an appropriate format string is applied.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I would have sworn that trailing zeroes were eliminated, but that appears to not be the case. It makes me wonder about all the questions I found on StackOverflow asking how to preserve trailing zeroes after conversion...