# Why is the fractional part of a double not showing with Console.Write, when it does with a decimal?

Tags: c#

Consider the following code:

```
decimal decimalVal = 4.00M;

double doubleVal = 5.00;

Console.Write(decimalVal);

Console.Write(doubleVal);
```

Why are the zeroes after the decimal in `decimalVal` displayed, but those after the decimal in `doubleVal` are not?

Comment: What do you mean "it returns as"?  How are you viewing its value?  4 is 4.0 is 4.0000000000, so obviously you are wondering about a specific form of string formatting.

Comment: I searched Google for the exact title of your question. The first hit was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net. Your question is a duplicate of that one.

Comment: John i got more from the post you mentioned in your answer, but i am still not clear why zeroes are not shown on double values?

Comment: `decimal` _must_ preserve the precision of the value it represents. `double` doesn't. When you define a decimal `4` with 3 significant figures, that is exactly what you get. The double `5.00` can be represented with the exact value `5`. How many decimal places it had is not encoded into the value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String contains trailing zeroes when converted from decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372014/string-contains-trailing-zeroes-when-converted-from-decimal)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference you're seeing is due to how `Console.Write()` was designed.

When you call `Console.Write` like this:

```
 Console.Write(decimalVal);

 Console.Write(doubleVal);
```

Under the covers, it's actually calling `ToString()` and passing it your current culture, equivalent to this:

```
 Console.Write(decimalVal.ToString(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture));

 Console.Write(doubleVal.ToString(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture));
```

Those two lines do not specify a format, so the general ("G") format for your culture is used, as noted in the documentation for [`Double.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hfd35ad(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Decimal.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b22a4x2(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
 Console.Write(decimalVal.ToString("G"));

 Console.Write(doubleVal.ToString("G"));
```

So what does the "G" format specifier output? Again, from the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#GFormatString):

> The result contains a decimal point if required, and **trailing zeros after the decimal point are omitted**. If the precision specifier is present and the number of significant digits in the result exceeds the specified precision, the excess trailing digits are removed by rounding.
>
> However, ***if the number is a Decimal* and the precision specifier is omitted ... trailing zeros are preserved.**
>
> *(my emphasis added)*

So the end result is that `Console.Write()` outputs...

- Your `double` value *without* trailing zeroes.
- Your `decimal` value *with* trailing zeroes.

At first, I chalked the difference up to "developer's choice", but then Raymond Chen and Jeff Mercado both commented on the underlying reason:

> It's because decimal remembers how much precision it has. 4.00M and 4.0M are not the same. (Although they compare equal.) Conversion to string reveals the precision. Double does not track precision. *~Raymond*
>
> `decimal` *must* preserve the precision of the value it represents. `double` doesn't. When you define a decimal ``4 with 3 significant figures, that is exactly what you get. The double `5.00` can be represented with the exact value `5`. How many decimal places it had is not encoded into the value. *~Jeff*

Additionally, from the [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) documentation:

> The scaling factor also preserves any trailing zeros in a Decimal number. Trailing zeros do not affect the value of a Decimal number in arithmetic or comparison operations. However, trailing zeros might be revealed by the ToString method if an appropriate format string is applied.

*(The "[scale factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_factor_(computer_science))" is a value that represents the fractional portion of the decimal - the portion after the decimal point.)*

What this means is, although 3.0m, 3.00m and 3.000000m are all considered equal when you compare them, the `Decimal` type stores an appropriate scale factor to ensure the trailing zeroes are not lost.

This does not apply to the [`Double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double(v=vs.110).aspx) type, where leading zeroes are not retained. Although, if you had a `double` and wanted to ensure at least a couple zeroes were displayed, you could specify a format:

```
Console.Write(doubleVal.ToString("F2"));  // outputs 5.00
```

Comment: It's because decimal remembers how much precision it has. 4.00M and 4.0M are not the same. (Although they compare equal.) Conversion to string reveals the precision. Double does not track precision.